# Running my own CDN alongside Amazons S3 for nearby visitors

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cdn

I am running a blog on shared webhosting. The website itself is on the hosting, but my files right now are on Amazons S3 CDN. I have made a bucket lockated in the US, and I have setup a virtual host with a free domain name I have. Summed up:

- Running a blog on mydomain.com
- Files on s3, bucket in the US, virtual host mybucket.cdnname.net

Now I myself am located in The Netherlands, Europe, and here is where my own webhosting server is located.

What I have seen in the speedtests, is that is takes some time before the files are fetched from amazon, I wanted to know if I can optimize this a little bit.

--

So actually what I want do if it is possible, is [to set up a cookieless domain](http://www.kevinworthington.com/set-cookieless-domain/) on my own server, and have a mirror of my files on the server right here. The files are already mirrored by default so that is no problem. Now for the visitors nearby, including myself, I want to just fetch the locally stored files.

Is this possible ? How do I tell `mybucket.cdnname.net` to not get the files from amazon, but instead get the files locally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my recommendation based on what you have described.

Set up an Amazon CloudFront distribution (CDN) that uses your S3 bucket as the origin server.

http://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/

You can set it up so that a hostname in your domain points to the CloudFront CDN for your distribution (e.g., cdn.example.com) similar to how you are doing it today for the S3 bucket.

CloudFront has an edge location in Amsterdam, so your customers should get great performance.  Plus, customers in other parts of the world will also benefit from CloudFront's many edge locations: http://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/#details

The network transfer costs for CloudFront are about the same as S3, though there is also a one-time network transfer cost for each time the edge location has to query the S3 bucket to fill its cache.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I know about cloudfront. I just don't want to pay the extra cost for it. I have my own server which will work perfect for the European region. Guess you don't have any information on setting that up and if that would be possible.

Comment: Saif: The cost for CloudFront should only be minimally higher than what you are doing today.

Comment: Ok, well maybe I will try it and see what the gains are. thank you for your response.